# Remove characters before period

Tags: python-2.7

qstring = www.facebook.com.

Using python, I need to remove everything until the first period, and remove the last period. I have to search through a text file to do this multiple times, so  I can't rely on a constant index.

So it should output ".facebook.com"

Comment: If all you want to do is to remove 'www' then `qstring.replace('www','')` would do it. To exclude the last full-stop, use slicing `qstring.replace('www','')[:-1]`

Comment: It  may no always be www and I can't rely on a constant index of -1 since it could occur in multiple locations in a text file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'd want to use regex for this task. The following pattern should suit your need. It looks for *www.* in a string and then grabs whatever that follows, if it matches the *domain.com* pattern.

```
r'(?:www.)(\w+.com)'
```

**Example:**

```
import re

qstring = 'www.facebook.com.'
>>>re.findall(r'(?:www.)(\w+.com)', qstring)
['facebook.com']
```